# Defparameter and equality predicate used in case macro

Tags: common-lisp

I have some global variables of type integer created with defparameter. I use these as keys in CASE clauses to match at test-key that was, at some point in my program, set to one of these global variables.

So far as I know, the CASE macro uses EQL (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#same), but I don't get a match: all is dumped into the otherwise clause. Code below summarises what's puzzling me.

- (defparameter snafu 123) => SNAFU
- (let ((x snafu)) (and (eq x snafu) (eql x snafu) (equal x snafu))) => T
- (let ((x snafu)) (case x (snafu 'yes) (t 'no))) => NO
- (let ((x snafu)) (cond ((eql x snafu) 'yes) (t 'no))) => YES

I don't understand why I don't get YES in the CASE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case clauses are not evaluated, they are taken literally.
This:

```
(case x
  (snafu 'yes)
  (t 'no))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(if (eql x 'snafu) 'yes 'no)
```

Note the quote before `snafu`: `x` is compared against the symbol `snafu` and not its value.

Comment: Thanks coredump. Makes sense. Like your IF equivalent. Leaving it to run for a little, but that seems to me like the correct answer.

Comment: Using read-time expansion solves the problem: (let ((x snafu)) (case x (#.snafu 'yes) (t 'no))) => YES

Comment: Only if the value is known at read-time and never changes, but yes it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since `case` is a macro, one can find out what code it generates:

```
* (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(case x
                            (snafu 'yes)
                            (t 'no))))

(LET ((#:G427 X))
  (DECLARE (IGNORABLE #:G427))
  (COND ((EQL #:G427 'SNAFU) NIL 'YES)
        (T NIL 'NO)))
```

One can see that `snafu` is used as a literal symbol, not a variable.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks Rainer.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on this before I saw @coredump's answer. Here is another example:

```
(progn (defparameter snafu 'y) 
       (let ((x snafu)) 
           (case snafu (y 'case-keys-are-constants))))
```

`; => CASE-KEYS-ARE-CONSTANTS`